# Parametrized server url for Angular autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use an [autocomplete](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) field

```
<angucomplete-alt id="members"
              placeholder="Search members"
              pause="400"
              selected-object="testObj"
              remote-url="http://myserver.com/api/user/find?s="
              remote-url-data-field="results"
              title-field="firstName,surname"
              description-field="email"
              image-field="profilePic"
              input-class="form-control form-control-small"/>
```

but i have several environments where I have to use it  development, test etc.

I would like to know how can I add the remote url

```
remote-url="http://myserver.com/api/user/find?s="
```

as a variable...so depending on the environment i might have

http://my_DEV_server.com/api/user/find?s=

http://my_TEST_server.com/api/user/find?s=

Since this is different then server side rendering where it would have been enough /user/find?s, how this can be solved having this client side rendering.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried url by escaping it using `encodeUriComponenet`?

Comment: is not about encoding ...is about using remote-url as a variable depending on the environment where the app is deployed...

Comment: thats my bad. you could have `ng-attr-remote-url="{{'http://'+ serverName +'.com/api/user/find?s='}}"` server name would come from scope

Comment: actually works with remote-url="/export-proposals/rest/calls?contains="

Comment: that means your issue is resolved?

Comment: should I add answer?

Comment: @chris I don't understand why you say this `remote-url="/export-proposals/rest/calls?contains="` works, I'll add whatever I suggested. Ok?

Answer (score 0):

This worked :

```
  <div class="padded-row">
        <div angucomplete-alt id="searchCall" placeholder="Search calls"
             pause="500" selected-object="selectedCall"
             remote-url="/export-proposals/rest/calls"
             remote-url-data-field="call" title-field="name"
             remote-url-request-formatter="remoteUrlRequestFn"
             description-field="callIdentifier" minlength="3"
             input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually is ok with relative path so no server info is needed :)